# Where can 助かる be used?

Tags: verbs, expressions, japanese-to-english

In a script, a guy gave seats to his show to two of his friends and said
"フフ。観客は多ければ多いほどいいからね。
助かるよ"

Would this imply him thanking his friends for going to his show? Or does it mean something else?

Comment: Yes. More or less it corresponds to *it helps*. [て助かる with inanimate subject](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93917/45489).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is right. ”助かる” means ”助けになる” in English, ”It become my aid”. So ”助かる” express ”thanks”.